# Server "really slow" what the first couple things to check?

Tags: linux, unix

A server is described as being "really slow".

What are the first couple of things you would check?

Comment: This is a pretty good question why 'not a real question' ?

Comment: For as start this question is too imprecise, @Marin. OP should mention: a) OS/distro (UNIX or Linux? Which flavour?) and web server used, b) what is the server serving and how is it configured - static/dynamic content? HTTP/HTTPS?, c) what does "slow" mean to him - connection time? response time? full page load time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to check? Your pager / other alarm system and graphs, of course! :-)

But if you don't have those available, you logon to server.

Most of the time if a server is *really* slow, it's because something is eating up the available memory and the server is swapping itself towards a slow death.

So, in case of a slowdown:

```
uptime
free
ps -eo size,command,pid | sort -nr | head -n 20
pkill -f name(s)_of_the_offending_process(es)
pkill -12 -f name(s)_of_offending_process(es) if the previous command didn't work
pkill -9 -f name(s)_of_offending_process(es) if the previous command didn't work
```

Or just

```
top
```

but with a *very* loaded server even running top might take ages.

Answer (score 1):

uptime command, to get the load averages. - then top command to see which processes are using the most resources (shift-M to list by memory, shift-P to list by cpu). then kill these if needed (kill -9 ),

then 'free' - to see memory usage, although its on the top command